# Printing inside a for loop

Tags: clojure

I was practicing one Clojure tutorial and had to ensure that a for loop was executed so I put a `println` command there, but it did not display messages.

So now I have got the question...

This code prints Tom's name:

```
(ns tutorial.core)
(defn -main []
  (println 'Jane)
  (for [a ['Tom]]
    (println a))
;;    'Kate
)



tutorial.core> (-main)
Jane
Tom
(nil)
tutorial.core>
```

but this not:

```
(ns tutorial.core)
(defn -main []
  (println 'Jane)
  (for [a ['Tom]]
    (println a))
    'Kate
)


tutorial.core> (-main)
Jane
Kate
tutorial.core>
```

Why? In which cases can we  expect that `println` will not print texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` is not a loop, it is a sequence comprehension which returns a lazy sequence. Your `for` expression will therefore only execute its side-effects (calls to `println`) when the returned sequence is evaluated. The REPL evaluates the values returned from your calls to `-main` so it can print them.

Your first example returns a lazy sequence which is evaluted by the REPL causing the `(println 'Tom)` call to be evaluated. Since `println` returns `nil`, the resulting sequence contains a single `nil` value - this is the `(nil)` you see in the output.

Your second example creates the same sequence but does not evaluate it, instead `'Kate` is returned from the function and the REPL prints that.

If you want an imperative for loop you should use `doseq`:

```
(defn -main []
  (println 'Jane)
  (doseq [a ['Tom]]
    (println a))
  'Kate)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Lee says, if you only want side effects like printing, a `doseq` is the best solution as it never returns a value other than `nil`.

If you do want to use a `for` loop, you can remove the laziness by wrapping it inside a `(vec ...)` expression, which will force the `for` loop to run immediately.  Thus we get:

```
(println :start)
(vec
  (for [a [1 2 3]]
    (println a)))
(println :end)
```

with result:

```
:start
1
2
3
:end
```

Without the `vec`, we get the behavior you saw:

```
(println :start)
(for [a [1 2 3]]
  (println a))
(println :end)
```

with result:

```
:start
:end
```

I almost never want a lazy result, as the uncertainty over *when* a computation occurs can make debugging difficult.  I use the above construct so often that I wrote [a small macro `forv`](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#focus-on-vectors) that always returns a vector result, similar to the `mapv` function.